# Sending information from one domain to another through the browser

Tags: asp.net-core, redirect, cookies

I'm fiddling with an application in a microservice architecture.

I have WebApp1 that is gathering information about the user in a form. That information will be validated by WebApp1 and , if valid, a base64 encoded string will be generated. This string needs to be passed to WebApp2 (which is completely separate) and the user then needs to be redirected to WebApp2

I want to capture the information that is being sent from WebApp1 to WebApp2 in a cookie.
Due to the possible size of the information, adding it to the query string is not an option, so I POST that information.

Now, whatever I do, WebApp2 doesn't create a cookie although the controller is being hit and no exceptions are thrown.

The jQuery on WebApp1 is simple:

```
    var redirectUrl = "https://webapp2/SetInfo;
    $('#go).submit(function () {
        $.ajax({ 
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            type: $(this).attr('method'), 
            url: $(this).attr('action'), 
            success: function (response) {
                $.post({
                    url: redirectUrl,
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function () {
                        window.location.replace(redirectUrl);
                    }
                })
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response)
            }
        });
        return false; 
    });
</script>
```

In WebApp2 I have the following code to receive the information from WebApp1 and set the cookie (I've validated that the information is indeed arriving at this method)

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> SetInfo()
        {
            var info= string.Empty;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                info= await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            }

            _httpContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("Info", info, new CookieOptions
            {
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(12),
                IsEssential = true
            });
            return Ok();
        }
```

As you can see, when setting the cookie, I also specified the `IsEssential` property, so that cannot be the problem.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you pls check my code snippet and take a try to test if it can set cookies first? Or could you pls add the details about the `$('#go').submit` method so that we can try to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've test your code snippet in my side and it worked for me, here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <script src="../js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button  id="loginButton">login</button>
        <script>
            var redirectUrl = "https://localhost:44396/SetInfo";
                $('#loginButton').click(function () {
                    $.post({
                        url: redirectUrl,
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function () {
                            window.location.replace(redirectUrl);
                        }
                    })
                });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my controller in my mvc web app with asp.net core 3.1:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebAppMvc.Controllers
{
    public class SetInfoController : Controller
    {

        public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
        {
            var info = string.Empty;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                info = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            }

            HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("Info", info, new CookieOptions
            {
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(12),
                IsEssential = true
            });
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

After setting cors policy, my frontend app can visit the mvc url "https://localhost:44396/SetInfo", you may try my code to check if it can set cookie first. And I also found your code snippet has a little mistake like below:

[image]